# GMap.NET connect Markers in C#

Tags: c#, google-maps, polygon, marker, gmap.net

I'm writing the below code, which is putting several markers (can be 3-20 ...) on the map with the right mouse click and working fine.
After that clicking on a separate button, I would like to connect them with a polygon.

I think I have to make a loop up from 0 to "markers.Markers.Count", but **how access to the Lat/Long position of the markers** ? I was searching everywhere, but no solution found. :-( Please help ! Thank You !
This code working fine:

```
 private void map_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) //add NEW markers
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            var position = map.FromLocalToLatLng(e.X, e.Y);
            var marker = new GMarkerGoogle(position, GMarkerGoogleType.blue);
            map.Overlays.Add(markers);
            markers.Markers.Add(marker);
        }
    }
```

**This code is the challenge** and shall come int he button click event:
Replace the below fix coordinates with the Lat/Long of the markers which are already on the map:

```
List<PointLatLng> points = new List<PointLatLng>();
for (int i = 0; i < markers.Markers.Count-1; i++)
{
 // Get the Lat/Long from the list of the markers -> X & Y  ***@@@ How to do this ??? @@@***
 // replace here the fix coordinates with X & Y:
 // points.Add(new PointLatLng(18.459806, 57.2874577));
}
//Populate polygon (just for info):
GMapPolygon polygon = new GMapPolygon(points, "My polygon");
polygon.Fill = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(50, Color.Red));
polygon.Stroke = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);                
polygons.Polygons.Add(polygon)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one overlay you can find the coordinates of the markers as follows:

```
map.Overlays(0).markers(i).position
```

The position is of type PointLatLng.

If you need the lat and lng seperated you can use

```
map.Overlays(0).markers(i).position.Lat
map.Overlays(0).markers(i).position.Lng
```